# Need a working OnImageUpload for Summernote using ASP.Net Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, summernote

I have a web application using ASP.NET Core 3.1, and one of the pages uses the Summernote text editor to compose content. I want to upload an image and save the image as an image url or save the images to a directory in SQL Server (instead of saving the images as base64). I tried some of the older posted results (they might have worked with older versions of Summernote or PHP), but nothing seems to work for me. So I'm not sure how to fix the issue. Does anyone know how to use the Summernote text editor that uploads images to a directory on the SQL server (not as base64)?

Summernote's web view:

```
<script>  
  
    $(''#Content'').summernote({  
        height: 300,                 // set editor height  
        minHeight: null,             // set minimum height of editor  
        maxHeight: null,             // set maximum height of editor  
        focus: true,                  // set focus to editable area after initializing summernote  
        callbacks: {  
            onImageUpload: function (files) {  
                for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {  
                    UploadImage(files[i]);  
                }  
            }  
        }  
    });  
  
    function UploadImage(file) {  
        var url = ''@Url.Action("UploadFile", "SummerNoteEx")'';  
  
        formData = new FormData();  
        formData.append("aUploadedFile", file);  
        $.ajax({  
            type: ''POST'',  
            url: url,  
            data: formData,  
            cache: false,  
            contentType: false,  
            processData: false,  
            success: function (FileUrl) {  
               // alert(FileUrl);  
                var imgNode = document.createElement(''img'');  
                imgNode.src = FileUrl;  
                $(''#Content'').summernote(''insertNode'', imgNode);  
            },  
            error: function (data) {  
                alert(data.responseText);  
            }  
        });  
    }  
</script>
```

After I do the above code, the Summenote text editor becomes an input text area field.